# Why does the leaf in "The rings of Akhaten" represent infinite possibilities

Tags: doctor-who

Clara says the leaf represents an infinite amount of untold potential that Clara's mother never saw because she died early.

That seemed far-fetched to me. She says the leaf is full of history and also full of stories that never happened.
Doesn't the leaf represent just one story? The story that happened? And not the infinite other possibilities?

If it did represent infinite other possibilities, wouldn't just any random object qualify for that?

Comment: I kind of thought Claire just got lucky here, and the leaf was the single unlikely event most responsible for her parents meeting, and thus setting in motion a very complex space time event(their daughter being shredded across the doctors entire timeline)

Comment: Don't You Know?  Leaves were Created by the God of Capitalization out of Ethermaterial from the Infinite Possibilities-Well in the Center of The Universe...Everyone Knows That!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Clara didn't know it at the time, that leaf represented her fracturing herself in the Doctor's timeline.

This is made very clear in *[The Name of the Doctor](http://jpgr.livejournal.com/159213.html)*.

> CLARA: (v.o.)
>   I don't know where I am. It's like I'm breaking into a million pieces. And there's only one thing I remember.
>
> ...
>
> I blew into this world on a leaf.
>
> EXT. STREET, DAY
>
> A MAN walks along the sidewalk, looking around to get his bearings. A leaf blows loose from a tree and covers his face, causing him to stagger into the road in front of an oncoming car. He pulls the leaf from his face and turns around to see the car and he freezes.
>
> CLARA: (v.o.)
>   I'm still blowing.
>
> ...
>
> DOCTOR: (v.o.)
>   You're my Impossible Girl. I'm sending you something - not from my past, from yours. Look up. Look. (a leaf falls from the sky) This is you, Clara. Everything you were or will be. Take it. (CLARA takes leaf) You blew into the world on this leaf. Hold tight. It will take you home.

So while the leaf didn't truly create *infinite* possibilities, it resulted in many, many alternate versions of the same person, and therefore pretty much countless stories.

She was probably wrong about the "untold potential" thing, and as @VapedCrusader mentioned, simply got lucky.

Comment: It did not create infinite possibilities, but it traversed them.  It entered the doctors timeline at the end, so it traversed infinite number of possible timelines.  It did not just traverse them alone, but confounded.  So it is infinity factorial possible timelines it actually traversed.